# dictionary decomposition and creating a new dictionary with identical values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, python-2.x

I have a dictionary `myDict`

```
{'1': 5, '2': 13, '3': 23, '4': 17}
```

I'm using this code, that has served me well, in order to find the key/value in `myDict` closest to a `targetVal`

```
answer = key, value = min(myDict.items(), key=lambda (_, v): abs(v - targetVal))
```

Assuming `targetVal` is `14`, `answer` returns:

```
('2': 13)
```

What I need to do now, is deal with identical values in `myDict`. For example, if `myDict` was now:

```
{'1': 5, '2': 13, '3': 23, '4': 13}
```

I need both those key/value pairs with the value `13`. 
In instances when the code (above) finds the closest value in `myDict`, and that value happens to appear more than once, i'd like to create a new dictionary. In this case, `answer` would return:

```
{'2': 13, '4': 13}
```

Is it possible to update the way `answer` is being found to account for instances when the closest value appears more than once?

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in myDict.items() if v == answer[1]}`

Comment: dict is not a good data structure for this kind of task.

Comment: I'll take a list of tuples, but i've been working with dictionaries lately, so i'm more comfortable manipulating them

Comment: @Chris_Rands, isn't `answer` just the 1 key/value though?

Comment: Did you not try my solution? `answer[1]` is the value, it works

Comment: @Chris_Rands I did, and got an error; It may very well have been user-error though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the minimum value first, then filter your `dict`.

```
>>> d = {'1': 5, '2': 13, '3': 23, '4': 13}
>>> target = 13
>>> min_ = min(d.itervalues(), key=lambda v: abs(v - target))
>>> {k:v for k,v in d.iteritems() if v == min_}
{'2': 13, '4': 13}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you found, `min` provides only one item which satisfies the minimum condition. You can construct a one-pass solution via a manual loop:

```
from math import inf

myDict = {'1': 5, '2': 13, '3': 23, '4': 13}
targetVal = 14

res = {}
diff = inf
for k, v in myDict.iteritems():
    current_diff = abs(v - targetVal)
    if current_diff <= diff:
        if current_diff < diff:
            diff = current_diff
            res.clear()
        res.update({k: v})

print(res)

# {'2': 13, '4': 13}
```

Comment: `float('inf')` should be fine too in case you don't want to import from `math`.

Comment: @timgeb, Thanks, learn something new! They are, of course, equivalent.